# Data not available outside of onBeforeMount - Composition API / Vue 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

In the single code component, I have the following script:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import ApiService from '../service/api'
import { reactive, onBeforeMount } from 'vue'

let pokemons = reactive([])

onBeforeMount(async ()=> {
  const response = await ApiService.getAll()
  pokemons = response.data.results
  return pokemons
})
</script>
```

Pokemons inside the OnBeforeMount exist, but not outside of it.

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

1. `onBeforeMount`'s callback function does not require a return value
2. `reactive` is meant to be used as a proxy to a `ref` value to watch all of the ref's nested properties.

```html
<template>
<ul>
  <li v-for="p in pokemons" :key="p.id">{{ p.name }}</li>
</ul>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import ApiService from '../service/api'
import { reactive, onBeforeMount, ref } from 'vue'

const allPokemon = ref([])
const pokemons = reactive(allPokemon)

onBeforeMount(async ()=> {
  const response = await ApiService.getAll()
  allPokemon.value = response.data.results
})
</script>
```